# how to redirect to login page if the users copy the link and paste it in the other tab

Tags: c#

I am Developing an application where the user enters their username and password to get into the application. If f he copies the url and pastes it into another other tab it should redirect to the login page with a warning message. How can I do this?

Comment: Why not allow the users to have multiple tabs - this would irritate me  intensely?

Answer (score 1):

If the main page is a POST (with data in the form), then the url won't contain the form fields. You could choose to check for this and redirect if missing.

This is a bit hacky though, and you should aim to use GET for the idempotent requests, and POST for mutation requests.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers treat multiple tabs as the same session, therefore the cookies are shared across the multiple tabs.

Even if you switch to cookieless, the url they copy will contain the cookieless authentication parameter.